# Autosize not working on fancy box 2 gallery

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I want to disable the auto size for fancy box gallery and set its width and height to a fixed value , i tried to change the settings with no success,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".fancybox-thumb").fancybox({
            prevEffect: 'none',
            nextEffect: 'none',
            autoSize: false,
                fitToView: false,
            width: 350,
                height:400,
            helpers: {
                title: {
                    type: 'outside'
                },
                overlay: {
                    opacity: 0.8,
                    css: {
                        'background-color': '#000'
                    }
                },
                thumbs: {
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100
                }
            }
        });
```

Any ideas how to override the default size and height ,

thanks

Comment: have you tried to set the css properties after you initialies the fancybox ?

Comment: na its adding inline styles onstart

Answer (score 0):

Set the API option `fitToView` to `false`.

`autoSize` is for '`inline`', '`ajax`' and '`html`' type of content where `width` and `height` are auto determined (dimensions are taken from the incoming content).

On the other hand, bear in mind that images can be displayed either, to fit into the viewport (`fitToView: true`) or in their original size regardless if this is bigger or not than the viewport (`fitToView: false`) .... but not in a different size other than the above (is like resizing images via html or css, which is a bad practice).

If you want your images to display in the same size of fancybox, then you have to enclose them in a container and use either ajax, inline or html type.